Same wallet creation details lead to different wallet address
I deployed Safe wallet matic:0x8c88A21Ad3BA7B475a2c1993E68bf83a61FcF473 via app.safe.global, with transaction: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/polygon/0xee2cc998c5bd835acbf397bd8bf931a8120d07525a5a784f8fa743d8b59b089f/debugger
By mistake, I have sent tokens to this wallet address on Fantom, so I try to create a Safe wallet on this address on Fantom.
If I run with the same creation details the following on cmd:
safe-creator --threshold 1 
--owners 0x3Db88B6C83276F7dc1748021a63A12ec97c79E36 
--safe-contract 0x41675C099F32341bf84BFc5382aF534df5C7461a 
--proxy-factory 0x4e1DCf7AD4e460CfD30791CCC4F9c8a4f820ec67 
--callback-handler 0xfd0732Dc9E303f09fCEf3a7388Ad10A83459Ec99 
--salt-nonce 0 
https://rpc.ankr.com/fantom 
0x123456789
(I did use the real private_key of the owners wallet like on Polygon)
I get:
Safe will be deployed on 0xDE8B213C0e7e6eEF893FDA9729D5ADCB2268823f, looks good? [y/N]
Why it wants to create a seperate wallet on Fantom as all 3 required Safe contracts are deployed on Fantom on the same address as on Polygon?

The  SafeToL2Setup.sol was the only contract missing on several chains. In the end, I copied the transaction input data from the deployment of ETH/Polygon and putted that as data in the Transaction Builder in both Fantom and Moonbeam Safe forks. Destination address = 0x914d7fec6aac8cd542e72bca78b30650d45643d7, Value = 0, Data = /transaction input data/
This successfully deployed SafeToL2Setup.sol on both chains.
safe-creator still gave me different address probably due to version differences (v1.3.0 versus v1.4.1) on these chains.
Therefore, I went again to the Transaction builder and now performed:
Destination address = 0x4e1dcf7ad4e460cfd30791ccc4f9c8a4f820ec67, Token Value = 0, Data = /copy transaction input data of deployments of your Safe wallets on supported chains like ETH/Polygon/
This did successfully created the same Safe wallet address on both chains.
However, now the Fork frontend notices that I am on a unsupported version of Safe and cannot perform any transactions from the front-end.
I build a script in Python with
requirements.txt:
safe-eth-py --pre
web3<7
That successfully transferred out my funds (on Tenderly for now). Make sure to keep a bit rest-balance for the native token otherwise you will get "GS011 : Could not pay gas costs with ether" error.

By simulating the same transaction with Tenderly but on Fantom, we can see that the call fails as the contract SafeToL2Setup.sol was not deployed at address 0xBD89A1CE4DDe368FFAB0eC35506eEcE0b1fFdc54 on this network (isContract() returns false).
Could you please try to deploy it (as well as potentially other missing contracts from this page) and then try again?
Please let me know if it worked (in which case feel free to mark the question as "Solved").
Thank you in advance  Best, Louis

Would I be able to deploy the contracts as-is on Polygon on the same address on Fantom?
Could you refer me to some guidance about it? I see here that these contracts are indeed deployed at a different address: https://docs.safe.global/advanced/smart-account-supported-networks?search=fantom&expand=250
